# PostgreSQL: exclude complete jsonb array if one element fails the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-10

Assume a table `json_table` with columns `id (int), data (jsonb)`.
A sample jsonb value would be

```
{"a": [{"b":{"c": "xxx", "d": 1}},{"b":{"c": "xxx", "d": 2}}]}
```

When I use an SQL statement like the following:

```
SELECT data FROM json_table j, jsonb_array_elements(j.data#>'{a}') dt WHERE (dt#>>'{b,d}')::integer NOT IN (2,4,6,9) GROUP BY id;
```

... the two array elements are unnested and the one that qualifies the WHERE clause is still returned. This makes sense since each array element is considered individually. In this example I will get back the complete row

```
{"a": [{"b":{"c": "xxx", "d": 1}},{"b":{"c": "xxx", "d": 2}}]}
```

I'm looking for a way to exclude the complete `json_table` row when any jsonb array element fails the condition

Comment: It is actually PostgreSQL 10.12. My mistake with the tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the condition to the `WHERE` clause and use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT data
FROM json_table j
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM jsonb_array_elements(j.data#>'{a}') dt 
                  WHERE (dt#>>'{b,d}')::integer IN (2, 4, 6, 9)
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with the following query:

```
select data 
from json_table
where jsonb_path_match(data, '!exists($.a[*].b.d ? ( @ == 2 || @ == 4 || @ == 6 || @ == 9))')
```

Comment: I cannot make this work. Whatever I try, I get is the following
`ERROR:  function jsonb_path_match(jsonb, unknown) does not exist`

Comment: I'm running PostgreSQL 10.12 actually

Comment: `jsonb_path_match()` requires Postgres 12